# How to see all values in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

If I entered multiple values in notebook, it returns only last one:

[image]

Is there any way to see all values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notebook output shows the result of the last expression.

You can explicitly print things you want to see:

```
print(2+3)
print(7+8)
```

Or you roll multiple values into one expression, like a tuple

```
( 2+3,
  7+8
)
```